# Connect AWS PostgreSQL to Power BI Desktop:The specified hostname was not present in the certificate

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to connect my PostgreSQL database to my Power BI desktop.

[image]

I downloaded the certificate from  `https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and installed in my machine. I am getting the same error as follows

```
Details: "An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'Npgsql.Tls.ClientAlertException: CertificateUnknown: Server certificate was not accepted. 
 Chain status: A certificate chain processed,
 but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
. The specified hostname was not present in the certificate.
   at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.SendAlertFatal(AlertDescription description, String message)
   at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.ParseCertificateMessage(Byte[] buf, Int32& pos)
   at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.TraverseHandshakeMessages()
   at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.<GetInitialHandshakeMessages>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.Tls.TlsClientStream.<PerformInitialHandshake>d__72.MoveNext()'"
```

My Npgsql version is 3.2.2.

Certificates are successfully imported like this.

[image: MMC]

I really do not know why is it still showing the error. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you connect with a PostgreSQL client? Without PowerBI that is.

Comment: @user5226582 Yeah, I use it with PgAdmin3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally access the database with an ODBC driver.

[image]

Select `Others` from `Get Data` list and select ODBC. Add the driver(if required) and set up the data source. Input your credentials and connect.

Good to go!

Comment: Did you manage to configure auto-refresh on PowerBI Services? I am struggling with it